# Apache2 react app + laravel REST api on same domain

Tags: debian, linux-networking, virtualhost, apache2, laravel

So my goal is I have my domain named `example.com`
conf for example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/public_frontend
        <Directory "/var/www/public_frontend">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine on
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

^ this conf is for my react app which contains an .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And I have my laravel backend layer which is reffered to in my app as `localhost:8000` here is it's conf file

```
Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:8000>
       
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias localhost

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/api/public

        <Directory "/var/www/api/public">
                Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess of the laravel api

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} . RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Mysql is correctly installed, Laravel is correctly installed

My problem is the following: My react app is timing out on the requests.

```
Error: timeout of 5000ms exceeded
    createError createError.js:16
    handleTimeout xhr.js:96
```

EDIT:
If I start my development server locally and try my APACHE server it does request to localhost on my LOCAL machine.

**How to bind apache2 request to localhost to the actual localhost?**

netstat output

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:xxxx            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

PS: I will leave the question Open, but I've ended up using nginx. Someone pointed out that my case should be possible with mod_proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You have a VirtualHost configuration based on names, i.e. when a request comes to port 8000, you have provided a VirtualHost that is prepared to serve requests for laravel.api (ServerName) or [www.laravel.api](http://www.laravel.api) (ServerAlias).

However, your application seems to use http://localhost:8000. I suggest you try to add localhost as ServerAlias and check if it works.

In addition, you have included some rewrite directives for the case in which "example.com" was the SERVER_NAME. They are useless if you are going to acces through laravel.api or [www.laravel.api](http://www.laravel.api).

Comment: So to be clearer you suggest adding `ServerAlias localhost` under my `*:8080` virtualhost.
I will try that thank you for the feedback I've been going without reading much doc, I've gone the whole day over mods, thank you for your time.

Comment: @Robles I tried, not result so far. But I have a clearer config now I will edit

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Nginx which was more simple to use for a rookie at setting up servers.
But I really wanted to learn apache and this was the roadblock I couldnt resolve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).